# Why private VMware network recognized as unidentified (public) network?

Tags: windows, networking, internet, lan, vmware

I have two virtual machines in VMware:

- Domain controller and DNS server (10.250.0.21)
- Application container (10.250.0.31)

I have a virtual NIC (VMnet1) on the host configured as "Host-only"
type in VMware Virtual Network Editor (10.250.0.1)

On the host I have an mssql inside a Docker on port 1433 - this is what I try to reach from the Application container (10.250.0.31) virtual machine.

But windows says that the VMnet1 is an unidentified network (therefore categorized as a public network profile). So in order to work, I have some options, but none of them is an elegant solution:

- Set the network profile type manually with the following PowerShell command: Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "VMware VMnet1" -NetworkCategory "Private"
  The problem is that after a windows restart, this setting will be lost and reset to public network profile. (Maybe task scheduler comes in handy, but meh.)
- In windows firewall, allow Docker Desktop's incoming traffic from
  Public network on port 1433. But I don't want to do this.
- Redefine the VMware virtual NICs as endpoint devices as described in
  this    article: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004813     This is
  permanent,    but this excludes these adapters from windows firewall
  and the NIC    exempt from all Windows Firewall access rules.
- Through secpol.msc, I set Unidentified Networks to Private Location
  type under the Network List Manager Policies tab.    But after this,
  every unidentified network will be private.

So I have the following questions in mind:

Why Windows NLA (Network Location Awareness) recognize my network as an unidentified network? Why Windows says to my private network which contains 3 machines that it's an unidentified network and not private?

Can I set or do anything with my network in order to be recognized as a private network?

Comment: ever sort this out?  battling the same thing at current and at startup of the host it first tries to connect to the "unidentified public network" which results in public firewall rule creation, loss of wake on lan packets being sent etc etc.

same results as you with powershell, interface metric seems to be irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, your Virtual Machine doesn't receive a default gateway from the "Host Only" network's DHCP Server.

Check this by running "ipconfig /all" on the VM.

I don't know which VMWare product you use but if it allows you to specify a default gateway in the DHCP configuration, this should solve your problem.

Otherwise, you can set a static IP address on your VM (with a default gateway) and it should be able to identify the network, even if there is no internet connection.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! :)